# Implements interface with generics, both methods have same erasure

Tags: java, android, generics, inheritance, interface

Here's my code. I've a base interface to define common function.

```
    interface BaseInterface<T> {
        void baseFunc(T param)
    }

    interface MyInterface1 extends BaseInterface<MyEntity1> {
        void func1()
    }

    interface MyInterface2 extends BaseInterface<MyEntity2> {
        void func2()
    }
```

And my class is:

```
    abstract class BaseClass implements BaseInterface<T> {
        // ...some common things
    }

    class ClassA extends BaseClass implements MyInterface1 {
        @Override
        public void func1() {...}

        @Override
        public void baseFunc(MyEntity1 param) {...}
    }

    class ClassB extends BaseClass implements MyInterface2 {
        @Override
        public void func2() {...}

        @Override
        public void baseFunc(MyEntity2 param) {...}
    }
```

Different class do the to do same things with different bean MyEntity1 and MyEntity2. So I defined baseFunc() with generic T.

But there's a problem here. "both methods have same erasure yet neither overrides the other baseFunc(T) and baseFunc(MyEntity1)..."

How to slove this problem?

By the way, It works fine when I removed the generic and move the baseFunc to MyInterface1 and MyInterface2. But I don't think it's the best way.

Comment: Something's wrong with `abstract class BaseClass implements BaseInterface<T>`. What's `T`?

Comment: Right, I reviewed my code and found this. abstract class BaseClass implements BaseInterface<T>                   change to  abstract class BaseClass<T> implements BaseInterface<T>    class ClassA extends BaseClass<MyEntity1> class ClassB extends BaseClass<MyEntity2>

Comment: @OscarZhang Sorry, I typed my answer before I noticed your comment.  Did that work for  you?  If so, you could convert your comment to an answer, in which case I'll delete mine; since your comment and my answer say basically the same thing.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem haha, it's ok. Your answer is is the solution. Keep it and it's more obvious to others who met the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declaration

```
abstract class BaseClass implements BaseInterface<T>
```

makes no sense, unless `T` is an actual class.  If it's implementing a generic interface, it needs to **either**

- be a generic class, **or**
- supply a type argument in place of the generic type parameter.

I believe what you actually wanted to write was

```
abstract class BaseClass<T> implements BaseInterface<T>
```

to keep `BaseClass` as a generic class.  You could then declare the other classes as

```
class ClassA extends BaseClass<MyEntity1> implements MyInterface1
```

and

```
class ClassB extends BaseClass<MyEntity2> implements MyInterface2
```

Then there would be no clash of the types passed to the `baseFunc` method.